# Adding openSuSe mono repository?

Tags: package-management, opensuse, mono, zypper

Question:

I want to install mono3 from here:
http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.0.3/linux/x64/

How can I add this link to the appropriate OpenSuse package installation program ?
I tried zypper ar http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.0.3/linux/x64/ mono3

but that yields "Repository type cannot be determined"
Repository mono3 is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the process used to find it would make you think it is, it isn't actually a repository, it is in fact just a simple file-share. In this situation, your best bet would be to remove all your openSUSE-provided mono packages (zypper rm), lock them (zypper al), and install (zypper in) the packages from the mono-project file-share.

Alternatively, mono in OpenSUSE Factory is now at the next major version (3.0.2), so you could also get your packages from there. Although, I'd recommend you don't - Factory isn't suitable for daily use, and there is a possibility packages from Factory may pull in other incompatible packages and cause serious issues.